# How to make the color hover change more softly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a demo for hover an image, its color change from gray to colours.

but, my color change effect is very crudity, I want more softly, such as a gradual change, ease-in, ease-out change color.

```html
<style>
  img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    width: 100%;
  }
  img:hover{
    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter: none;
  }
  .grid-item { width: 80px; 
    height: 80px ;
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  .grid-item--width2 { 
    width: 400px; 
  }
</style>

<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://mapchart.net/img/world-divided-population-map.png">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://mapchart.net/img/world-divided-population-map.png">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/masonry/4.2.1/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="">
    $(function(){
        $('.grid').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            columnWidth: 80,
            gutter: 10
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to image style

```
img {
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add transition on your object:

```
img {
    transition: 0.7s;
}
```